Multiple Web APIs and common hangfire usage in .net
I have an application that contains multiple web api projects in .net. I am using MongoDb. Now I want to add a common hangfire to this application. In other words, there will be a single hangfire db and all web api projects will manage jobs through this db. For this, I added an extension to my common class library.

Common/HangfireExtensions.cs

public static class HangfireExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddHangfireServices(this IServiceCollection services, string mongoConnectionString, string dbName, string projectName)
    {
        GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AppJobFilterAttribute(projectName));

        services.AddHangfire(config =>
        {
            config.UseMongoStorage(mongoConnectionString, dbName, new MongoStorageOptions
            {
                MigrationOptions = new MongoMigrationOptions
                {
                    MigrationStrategy = new MigrateMongoMigrationStrategy(),
                    BackupStrategy = new NoneMongoBackupStrategy()
                },
                CheckConnection = true,
                CheckQueuedJobsStrategy = CheckQueuedJobsStrategy.TailNotificationsCollection
            });
        });

        services.AddHangfireServer(options =>
        {
            options.Queues = new[] { Constants.AppNumber.ToString() };
        });
        return services;
    }
}

Here, by using filter, I wanted each web API project to run the jobs I defined in it. But even though I use the filter, I still get an error like this because the web API projects are trying to run jobs that are not defined in other projects:

 Recurring job 'AJobAsync' can't be scheduled due to an error and will be disabled.
      Hangfire.Common.JobLoadException: Could not load the job. See inner exception for the details.
       ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'A.API, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.


My codes in projects A and B are as follows:

A.API/Program.cs

builder.Services.AddHangfireServices(connectionString, hangfireDatabase, "A.API");
app.UseHangfireDashboard();

var jobService = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IJobService>();
RecurringJobs.Initialize(jobService);


A.API/RecurringJobs.cs

public static class RecurringJobs
{
    public static void Initialize(IJobService service)
    {
        RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(nameof(service.AJobAsync));

        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
            recurringJobId: nameof(service.AJobAsync),
            methodCall: () => service.AJobAsync(),
            cronExpression: "0 */1 * ? * *", // Every 1 minute
            queue: Constants.AppNumber.ToString()
        );
    }
}


A.API/IJobService.cs

public interface IJobService
{
    Task AJobAsync();
}

Assume that there is a B.API in this structure as well. It also has specific jobs defined for it.
When these two projects run at the same time, I get the error I mentioned above because it tries to run the jobs defined in both of them. My request is that only project A should run the jobs defined in project A, and only project B should run the jobs defined in project B.

You have an explanation here: https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/difference-between-addhangfire-and-addhangfireserver/6731

Hi If you are using Version 1.8.0 or later u can use https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.DynamicJobs
